# The destroy_path with polymorphism

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, polymorphism

I have this problem, an error message appears.

```
No route matches {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"favorites"} missing required keys: [:favoritable_id]
```

I try to add a destroy action to a polymorphic object

Here is the destroy method

```
<%= link_to "Supprimer", destroy_favorite_path[:favoritable_type], :data => {:confirm => 'Are you sure?'}%>
```

Here is the controller

```
class FavoritesController < ApplicationController
  def destroy
    case favorite_params[:favoritable_type]
    when "Symbole"
      @favoritable = Symbole.find(favorite_params[:favoritable_id])
    when "User"
      @favoritable = User.find(favorite_params[:favoritable_id])
    when "Post"
      @favoritable = Post.find(favorite_params[:favoritable_id])
    when "Sentence"
      @favoritable = Sentence.find(favorite_params[:favoritable_id])
    end
    if @favoritable.present?
      @favorite = Favorite.where(favorite_params.merge(user_id: current_user.id))

      if @favorite.destroy_all
        #flash[:notice] = "Successfully unfavorited"
      end
    end

    respond_to do |format|
        format.js { render :ajax_update_favorites }
    end
  end

  private

  def favorite_params
    params.permit(:favoritable_type, :favoritable_id)
  end
end
```

And here are the routes

```
post 'favorites/:favoritable_id', to: 'favorites#create', as: "create_favorite"
  get 'favorites', to: 'favorites#index'
  delete 'favorites/:favoritable_id', to: 'favorites#destroy', as: "destroy_favorite"
```

I want the object be suppress and we are no redirected to another page but I don't know what is wrong. Thank you for your help. Tell me if you want more infos.

Comment: because it's polymorph structure. How will you write the path?

Comment: yes but there is a route error No route matches [GET] "/favorites/41" ?

Comment: @spickermann `class Favorite < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Favorite.create(user_id: User.last.id, favoritable_id: Symbole.last.id, favoritable_type:"Symbole")
  belongs_to :favoritable, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :user

    validates :user_id, uniqueness: {
    scope: [:favoritable_id, :favoritable_type],
    message: 'can only favorite an item once'
  }
end`

Comment: I can't because the routes are like that `post 'favorites/:favoritable_id', to: 'favorites#create', as: "create_favorite"
  get 'favorites', to: 'favorites#index'
  delete 'favorites/:favoritable_id', to: 'favorites#destroy', as: "destroy_favorite"`

Comment: :favoritable_id is missing. And polymorphic routes are not meant to ignore REST. Please move each favourite destroy into its resource controller (users_controller, sentences_controller, posts_controller etc.). Then you don't need to check the type in the controller.
Furthermore you do something like:
<%= link_to "Supprimer", your_object, method: :delete, remote: true %>

Comment: Thank you Christian I missed remote: true